# Is it possible to use different version of node for different node script at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, nvm

I am currently using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). Is it possible to use specific node version for specific script? For example...

With node 6

```
forever start -a -l $MYPATH/forever.log -e $MYPATH/err.log -c "node --max_old_space_size=20" $MYPATH/script_with_node_version_6.js
```

With node 8

```
forever start -a -l $MYPATH/forever.log -e $MYPATH/err.log -c "node --max_old_space_size=20" $MYPATH/script_with_node_version_8.js
```

Comment: Perhaps `nvm exec v8 forever start ...`?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, you should be able to do this by explicitly pointing to your executible. Since you mention you're using nvm (assuming [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)), you can check out where your versioned node.js installations live.

```
nvm root
```

> Current Root: C:\Users\you\AppData\Roaming\nvm

Or - wherever this command returns. Then simply point to them in your specified scripts instead of your $PATH `node`

```
forever start -c "C:\Users\you\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.11.0\node.exe v6.js"

forever start -c "C:\Users\you\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.1.2\node.exe v8.js"
```

---

If you're on a linux box or leveraging [bash on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about) you may be able to capitalize on some of the nice features `nvm` offers. Notably, [nvm exec](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#usage)

> Or, you can run any arbitrary command in a subshell with the desired
>   version of node:

This may look as such...

```
forever start -c "nvm exec 8.1.2 node v8.js"
```

Check out their examples, you may be able to streamline your command even more as your top comment suggests...